# Encoding csv error with Pandas - have to encode one csv file but not the other -both have same encoding

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am using pandas to read in csv data to my python script.
Both csv files have the same encoding (Windows-1252).
However with one of the files I get an error when reading the csv file with pandas, unless I specify the encoding parameters in pd.read_csv().

Does anyone know why I need to specify the encoding in one csv and not the other? Both csv's contain similar data (strings and numbers).

Thank you

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas (at least version 1.3.3) uses UTF-8 encoding by default, even on Windows (see the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cd13e3a42d03f2c3f93b1de3e04352d01aac2241/pandas/io/common.py#L595)). UTF-8 has some forbidden bytes (see the red cells in the [codepage layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout)). However, these bytes are allowed in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set). Therefore, I suppose one of your files has some of these bytes that are not allowed in UTF-8. Perhaps there is a data entry error that mistakenly put a ø instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

That just means that one of the files has a character outside the range 0x00 to 0x7F.  It's only the highest 128 values where the encoding makes a difference.  All it takes is one n-with-tilde or one smart quote mark.